# my exam question?

Tags: word-usage, idioms, reading

I had an exam yesterday and this question was challenging for me

> jack is not the kind of man____ work.
>
> 1. had avoided
> 2. avoiding
> 3. to avoid
> 4. avoids

I answered 2 and someone said I was wrong. What is the correct and why please.

Answer (score 3):

the answer was 3

`kind of man` implies a character trait, so `V+ING` cannot be used in this context. The infinitive was needed.

3 - `Jack is not the kind of man to avoid work`

the answer 4 does not make sense since there is already a conjugated verb in the sentence

Answer (score 3):

**The correct answer should be :**

> *3. Jack is not the kind of man **to avoid** work.*

Here's an example of how the sentence should have been structured to make the other options viable.

> *1 - Jack is not the kind of man **you'd believe had avoided** work.*
>
> *2 - Jack is not the kind of man **to be avoiding** work.*
>
> *4 - Jack is not the kind of man **who avoids** work.*